# Create HDI Container automatically in Cloud Foundry

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-cloud-foundry

I have an issue. I am working of db project in SAP Business Application Studio. I want to make sure that a new HDI container is created in cloud foundry during deployment of the project.

In mta.yaml I have specified the following:

```
type: com.sap.xs.hdi-container
   parameters:
     service: hana
     service-plan: hdi-shared
   properties:
     hdi-service-name: ${service-name}
```

And it’s not working. Moreover, it will deploy without error only when it’s already connected to HDI container…

Can someone please point out what am I doing wrong?